# Delete rows with an error for each sheet in a single workbook

Tags: excel, vba, syntax-error

I have a spreadsheet with 7 identical sheets just displaying slightly different data. It is a mixture of data and charts with each cell referencing my "Output" sheet through a series of index matches. I simply want it to delete rows where cell (ii,2) has fallen over (there is no data for this particular data point in the output sheet) for each of my 7 sheets. The last row of data on each of my sheets is 212 and I always want it to reference cell (ii,2) - the second column data point for each row. Because there are blocks with charts and no data I can not use the End Xlup method

I have the following code:

```
Dim lr As Long
Dim sh As Integer
Dim ii As Long


lr = Cells(212, 2)

For sh = 1 To Worksheets.Count

    For ii = lr To 1 Step -1

        If Worksheets(sh).Cells(ii, 2) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then

            Worksheets(sh).Rows(ii).EntireRow.Delete

        End If

    Next ii

Next sh
```

It runs fine but it's doing nothing and I can't work out why

Comment: You should learn to step through your code which is the first step in debugging your code. Then you would see that presumably `lr` does not return the value you think it does, it is the value of B212 in whichever sheet is active when you run the code. Shouldn't `lr=212`?

Comment: Changing to lr=212 results in a "Run-timer error '13': Type Mismatch"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the comment above you cannot directly check for a specific type of error, first you need to check whether the cell contains any error at all to avoid a type mismatch error. The absence of this error suggests that your loop is not running at all.

```
Sub x()

Dim lr As Long
Dim sh As Integer
Dim ii As Long

lr = 212 'Cells(212, 2)

For sh = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    For ii = lr To 1 Step -1
        If IsError(Worksheets(sh).Cells(ii, 2)) Then
            If Worksheets(sh).Cells(ii, 2) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
                Worksheets(sh).Rows(ii).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next ii
Next sh

End Sub
```